# casting removes leading zeros

Tags: php, casting

Can someone tell me why when I cast a string of say 00332 I only get back 332? It removes the leading zeros and saves the data in the same format.

Thanks

---

```
this->_gate   = (string) $this->_linkID->QuoteSmart($gate);
```

Comment: Are you casting a string to a string? An int to a string? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, a string to a string. I'm new to type casting so...

Comment: Your right! What's even weirder is that I removed all but the variable and STILL get the leading zeros removed.. What gives?

Comment: Hang on... I'm running the var through addslashes(). I'm wondering if this is what is removing the zeros.

Comment: addslashes() shouldn't touch any 0s. It should just put a slash before any char that needs to be escaped like ' etc..

Comment: I'm out of answers.. I really stumped on this because I am using POST to carry the var to my query and from there, it is filtered through quotesmart which escapes any quotes then goes through addslashes into the db.

Comment: What happens if you remove the (string) cast ? Does it work then ?

Comment: No, even if I remove everything but the variable, it still was saved incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say because the leading zeros don't have any importance when cast to an integer.

Maybe you should leave it as a string if you need those leading zeroes, and only cast `(int)` on any math needed to be performed (though you could just use the string too, PHP will figure it out)

**edit**

After seeing the example, I'd want to echo the value before you cast to string (so I can confirm something fishy isn't going on with you QuoteSmart method (or the value your sending as a param, $gate)

Comment: Hey Alex. You heloed me the other day, Thanks for the help! I posted above a sample.

Comment: The val I'm sending is 00432 and after its cast, I only wind up with 432 being saved in the database. :/  So, prior to casting, I can echo 00432 and afterwards only get 432. Let me remove the quotesmart function and see if that fixes it. brb

Comment: Also, Jim, what type is on the field of your DB ? This could be affecting what is saved in the DB too.

Comment: It will need to be something like VARCHAR, not an INT variety (which will most probably destroy useless information to an integer, such as leading `0`s)

Comment: Well, I like how your thinking Alex but the field is set to char which will accept any type of input.

Comment: Well, if you're only reason for casting to string here is for security, I would ignore it. I perform all security related things on external vars as they come in, first and foremost. So either your var is secure already, or you're using register_globals, which isn't good.

Comment: Just curious, which other question did I help you with ? I can't recall (Saturday morning here...)

Comment: I had a PHP question and for the life of me, I cannot remember what exactly it was. You came through for me though. It was only a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Don't cast strings to strings, or any type to the same type for that matter. Typecasting is for changing something from one type to another.

Comment: @Jim, it really depends, if you're accepting a user input which MUST be a number (example, a $_GET['id']) then it'd be a good idea to cast to an integer with (int)$_GET['id']. It will blow away any leading alpha stuff, and if it can't get to any useful numbers, will become 0.

Comment: However, other precautions need to be taken depending on the context... example, vars printed to page should be htmlspecialchars()'d and vars in a database query should be mysql_real_escape_string or the equivalent for your DB. In fact, just use parameterised queries. Check out www.php.net/pdo

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.. I think Alex may have a point about the quotesmart function changing the output. I am going to remove it and see what I get.

Comment: Of course, there's a whole lot more security things to be taken into account for, but luckily there is a lot of stuff on the web. Research wisely!

Comment: OK, removing quotesmart did nothing. Here is what I have now:
$this->_gate   = (string) $gate;

0433 returns 433. This field can be a mixture of string or int.

Comment: Check out my comment to my answer Jim, ensure your DB has the right type for your column.

Comment: I saw that Alex. Thanks. I am using char. I'm tracing the var from the html form into my class right now and inside the methid, I can still echo the proper value. If I edit mysql directly and put a val of 003322 it saves it as exactly that so I'm confused as to what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ php -r 'var_dump((string)"00123");'
string(5) "00123"
```

Looks like the cast isn't your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was what got me looking for the problem elsewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you cast it to and why? Let's see the code. If you cast to integer, yeah, integers don't have leading zeroes, so they disappear. No surprise.

Comment: Please have a look above. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is why it was dropping the leading zeros. It was NOT casting nor addslashes. What I did was to quote the variable (which quotesmart should be doing anyhow but didn't for some reason) Once I quoted the variable, I got the value saved correctly. If Im not mistaken, quotesmart will only work on strings and not ints.